# How to enable using String modification methods in Android

Tags: java, android, replace, trim

This may be a very simple question. I am new to Java programming. I couldn't find an answer in other threads.

When I try to use trim(), replace() or split() functions in Activity.java in Android Studio, they are not recognized. I understand I need to import some classes or enable some settings but don't know what to do.

```
element = element.trim();
```

trim is red and it says "Cannot resolve method trim" when I hover it.

Why?

Comment: What is `element`? Is it a `String`? Show us. If it's not a `String`, why do you expect it to have the `String` method `trim`?

Comment: place the cursor to the end of trim() and press`alt+ins` or `ctrl+enter` in Android Studio. it will show you the import suggestions.

Comment: Ah right, I am an idiot. element is of type EditText. So I need to get its content first. So stupid. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element = element.toString().trim();
```